# how fix "A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget"

Tags: dart

I am new to flutter getting this error A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget. while I am damn sure I am passing a value to this widget.

```
 RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Save'),
        onPressed: () {
          final Map<String, dynamic> product = {
            'titile': titleValue,
            'description': descriptionValue,
            'price': priceValue,
            'image': 'assets/33.jpg',
          };
          widget.addProduct(product);
```

Comment: Can you please add an extract of your code?

Comment: @TristanPct please check now.

Comment: You are right to be sure because you are passing a value to the `Text` widget. Are you sure that is the only text widget in that file?

Comment: Issue resolved. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

you can use toString() method it is dealing when null value comes in the Text widget
like Text(foo.toString());